# How to find the level of a node in a binary tree without passing the level as an argument to the function?

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

This is the code to find the level while passing level as an argument to the function.

```
int findLevel(node* root, node* ptr,
    int level = 0) {
if (root == NULL)
    return -1;
if (root == ptr)
    return level;
// If NULL or leaf Node
if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    return -1;
// Find If ptr is present in the left or right subtree.
int levelLeft = findLevel(root->left, ptr, level + 1);
int levelRight = findLevel(root->right, ptr, level + 1);
if (levelLeft == -1)
    return levelRight;
else
    return levelLeft;}
```

But how to find without passing level as an argument? Should I have level in my node struct? How to initialize it then?

This is my struct and insert right now:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int value;
    bst left;
    bst right;
} node;

node* bst_insert (node* root, int value){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        root->value = value;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
    }
    else{
        if(value > root->value)
            root->right = bst_insert(root->right, value);
        else
            root->left = bst_insert(root->left, value);
    }

    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to convert you recursive algorithm to an iterative version.  Then you can store the level in a local variable, and keep track of your search path using a stack (for depth first search (DFS)).

You can, as you mentioned, store the level in each node, but that is technically passing it as an argument.  On insert, you set the level of the new node to the level of the parent + 1.  Here is a minimal implementation of this idea:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node;

struct node {
    int value;
    int level;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

struct node *node_new(int value, int level) {
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    assert(n);
    n->value = value;
    n->level = level;
    n->left = 0;
    n->right = 0;
    return n;
}

void node_insert(struct node **current, int value) {
    // leaf
    struct node **next = value < (*current)->value ? &(*current)->left : &(*current)->right;
    if(!*next) {
        *next = node_new(value, (*current)->level + 1);
        return;
    }

    // non-leaf
    node_insert(next, value);
}

int main() {
    struct node *root = node_new(10, 0);
    node_insert(&root, 5);
    node_insert(&root, 20);
    node_insert(&root, 30);
}
```

Comment: How to implement this: 'you set the level of the current node to the level of the parent + 1'?

Comment: Fix your bst_insert to connect each new node to your  tree.  I would rename root to current in your current code.  The root node pointer is usually stored in a struct Tree.  When you insert the first node, you notice that your root node is null, so you set level to 0 (or 1 depending on how you want to count) in it's node.  Then the next insert you figure out if the new leaf goes left and right, then you set, for example, current->left = malloc(sizeof(node) and current->left->height = current->height + 1.